# MySQL stored procedure - compare string values in select

Tags: mysql

The comparison in the stored procedure does not work (the COUNT is always 0)

```
BEGIN

DECLARE health_var INT(3);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE service_name TEXT;
DECLARE service_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT service FROM service_health;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


OPEN service_cursor;
    read_loop: LOOP
                        
        FETCH service_cursor INTO service_name;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        
        SELECT service_name;
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events where service = service_name;
        SELECT service, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM events GROUP BY service HAVING cnt > 1;

    END LOOP read_loop;
CLOSE service_cursor;

END
```

However, when I try to show service_name in the loop:

```
SELECT service_name;
```

it works.
So the issue is in the comparison.

Tried to replace = with LIKE, change variable datatype (service is VARCHAR(1000)).

Tables definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `ticketno` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reporting_level` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdon` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assigned_to` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assignment_group` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `short_description` varchar(10000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `incident_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trt` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `write_timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service_health` (
  `service` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `general_health` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `incident_health` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_health` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `rfc_health` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `problem_health` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `write_timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Please publish sufficient sample data as text that enables us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/s43UaK6j Please include table definiions as text.

Answer (score 0):

It would had been better if you had shared your DB schema too. But with whatever information you have provided, I made an attempt like this. Check it out if it works for you.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE your_procedure_name()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE service_name TEXT;
    DECLARE query TEXT;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_counts (service TEXT, count INT);
    DECLARE service_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT service FROM service_health;
    OPEN service_cursor;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH service_cursor INTO service_name;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET query = CONCAT('INSERT INTO temp_counts (service, count) SELECT ''', service_name, ''', COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE service = ''', service_name, ''';');
        PREPARE stmt FROM query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP read_loop;
    CLOSE service_cursor;
    SELECT service, count FROM temp_counts WHERE count > 1;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_counts;
END
```

Comment: I am getting the error: "/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE service_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT service FROM service_health;
    OPEN ' at line 12 */"

Comment: I have amended the SQL in the main Answer Cell. Please try it out>
That's the point I can go up to. Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: still the error: /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE service_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT service FROM service_health;
    OPEN ' at line 12 */

Comment: Tried setting delimiters?